# Error al llamar varios procedimientos almacenados en MySQL con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, stored-procedure

***Hola, espero que me puedan colaborar***

Estoy tratando de llamar dos procedimientos almacenados en Mysql, y siempre sin importar el orden solo funciona el primero y el otro muestra el siguiente error:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\MYFIP_1.0\order_cuentas.php

***La idea es poder restar los gastos de los ingresos, para saber el disponible, por ende hay que poder recuperar cada resultado, para mostrar el disponible en pantalla.***

Ya los valide en consola y ambos funcionan perfectamente, eh aqui el codigo:

```
include "connections/config.php";

$sql_suma_g = "CALL sumar_gastos('$usuario','$usuario')";
$result_suma_g = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql_suma_g);
$row_suma_g = mysqli_fetch_array($result_suma_g);
echo $row_suma_g[0];

$sql_suma_i = "CALL sumar_ingresos('$usuario','$usuario')";
$result_suma_i = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql_suma_i);
$row_suma_i = mysqli_fetch_array($result_suma_i);
echo $row_suma_i[0];
```

hay que decir que solo funcionan si pongo la conexion antes de cada consulta.

> include "connections/config.php";

quisiera saber el porque de este error y como solucionarlo de una mejor manera.

de antemano gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

### Problema:

1. No puedes hacer 2 whiles para una misma consulta `fetch_array`, ya que devuelve un [recurso](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.resource.php). Este recurso tiene su propio puntero interno (el contador de filas ya leídas). `mysqli_fetch_array()` avanza dicho puntero interno por lo que al llegar al 2º while no quedará ninguna fila por leer.

### Solución:

La posible solución es añadir el valor de este recurso a un array de filas.

```
$filas=array();
while($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($row_suma)){
    $filas[] =$fila;
}
foreach($filas as $fila){
    print_r($fila);
}
foreach($filas as $fila){
    print_r($fila);
}
```

### Editado:

Para hacer multiples consultas dentro de una conexión en vez de utilizar `mysqli_query` puedes utilizar [`mysqli_multi_query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.multi-query.php) que devolverá un array de consultas existen [ejemplos -> PHP.NET](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php)

```
mysqli_query("CALL sumar_gastos('$usuario','$usuario');CALL sumar_ingresos('$usuario','$usuario');");
```

Comment: hola @matahombres las dos consultas no son identicas, una suma ingresos y otra gastos.

Comment: Oh, entonces utiliza [`mysqli_multi_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.multi-query.php) que puedes utilizar varias consultas